# Responses is returned as string and not as json - Python

Tags: python, json, django, response

I am trying to send back (get requests) a json but instead is sending a json as string

```
"{"series": [{"name": "Count of Signups", "type": "column", "data": [4, 29, 10]}, {"name": "Average of signups over last 3 Months", "type": "line", "data": [NaN, NaN, 14.0]}], "labels": ["2020-06", "2020-07", "2020-08"]}"
```

The disire result its the same but as json without the quotes (not as string)

```
    {
        "series": [{
            'name': "Count of Signups",
            'type': "column",
            'data': [4, 29, 10],
        },
        {
            'name': "Average of signups over last 3 Months",
            'type': "line",
            'data': [NaN, NaN, 14.0],
        }],
        "labels": ["2020-06", "2020-07", "2020-08"]
    }
```

here is my code, my view in django:

```
def Apiname(request):
    start_date = request.GET.get('start')
    end_date = request.GET.get('end')

    res = {
        "series": [{
            'name': "Count of Signups",
            'type': "column",
            'data': [],
        },
        {
            'name': "Average of signups over last 3 Months",
            'type': "line",
            'data': [],
        }],
        "labels": []
    }

    df = pd.read_csv("mycsvfile.csv")

    mask = (df['MonthYear'] >= start_date) & (df['MonthYear'] <= end_date)
    df = df.loc[mask]

    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        res['series'][0]['data'].append(row['Count_of_signups'])
        res['series'][1]['data'].append(row['signups_3mth_moving_average'])
        res['labels'].append(row['MonthYear'])

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(res), content_type="application/json")
```

I tried with to_dict to parse it to json but got the same results, the most strage is that i have another APIs with the same structure and they return a json idk why this is happening

Comment: "json" is not a thing in Python. It's just a notation, which can be represented as a string or a dictionary. So no, your other APIs most likely also do not return JSON to Python.

Comment: @matszwecja yes but what i mean is that souldnt be retuened as string, it should be as literal a "dict"/"object" (json)

Comment: just do `json.loads(response)`

Comment: Also check Django Rest Framwork [https://www.django-rest-framework.org/]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed, it was the NaN values on the dict, now works fine if i replace them for "0"